# SSH connection to my Amazon EC2 instance refused from a Windows Box

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Trying to ssh into my amazon EC2 linux instance from a Windows 10 box. I have got openssh for windows from https://www.mls-software.com/opensshd.html . I know that I am behind a corporate firewall and  a web proxy. My Inbound rule settings on the EC2 instance is

[image]

```
ssh  -i "awslamp.pem"  ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

gives

```
port22: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried "my ip" in inbound rule settings? Also, try allowing SSH from all IP addresses for troubleshooting purposes. I know that it's not the recommended settings. It's just for troubleshooting and making sure that your corporate network allows you to connect to it. Do not forget to change the settings back to custom.

Comment: I have allowed Inbound Connections from of Type All Traffic from source 0.0.0.0/0  . Still conneciton refused. Does it mean corporate network doesn't allow.   If it doesn't allow, what else can I do ?

Comment: Hi, have you try to telnet the port is open or not.

`telnet xx-xx-xx-xx 22`

Comment: @ShornJacob. I guess you should try talking to your network admins. It could be possible that they have some sort of gateway. Also try pinging/using telnet the host to see if the port is open as Jogendra mentioned. Further, see if you can get more details using verbose while doing ssh using -v. **ssh -v username@hostname**.